# Saving audio files in iPod library

Tags: iphone

I want to record sound as part of my application. Is it possible to save my audio files in ipod library and sync using iTunes?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can record sound, and no, you can't save into the iPod library.  The sound you record will not readily sync with iTunes.